# can not run my first spider: "scrapy crawl quotes" returns scrapy is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: scrapy

I am following to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial.

1. scrapy startproject tutorial is done.
2. Saving quotes_spider.py under the tutorial/spiders directory is done.
3. change directory to tutorial directory is done. I see there a folder named tutorial and a file named scrapy.cfg
4. scrapy crawl quotes returns an error described in the subject.

What`s wrong? Could anybody help?

**[UPD]**
After rebooting my laptop the error disappeared. The problem is solved.

Comment: Which path level did you run this command

Comment: What do you mean? I am ussing virtualenv as described in the manual, no any pathlevels are described there.

Comment: If you ran `scrapy startproject tutorial` command without error as you say, I don't see a reason for the error you report. How exactly did you ran those commands? Can you attach screenshot of a command line with the session?

Comment: Thank you guys! I occasionally rebooted my laptop yesterday, so today scrapy crawl quotes returns something usefull without errors. I am walking throug the tutorial further.